# Find the average of 50 random numbers in an array- C Programming

Tags: c, arrays, random, numbers, average

I have already figured out how to display 50 random numbers in an array. The numbers are between 1 to 500. I am having trouble with finding the average in my current code, as it only displays itself as zero. Can someone help me?

```
int num[SIZE] = {0};
int count = 0;
int i;
int total = 0;
int value;
float avg = 0;
srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); //SEEDS RAND FUNCTION

printf("Display the numbers in the range of [1, 500]. \n"); //displays random numbers

    for(i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
    {
        value = rand()%500 + 1;
        printf("%i\n", value); 
        total = total + num[i];
        avg = (float)total/50;
    }

//Display Output
printf("The average of all the numbers is %i \n", avg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
total = total + num[i];
```

Here `num[i]` and the whole array contains 0. So `total` will remain 0. So,you need

```
num[i]=value;
```

Just before calculating `total`. Also,the average should be calculated after the loop. Don't forget use `%f` instead of `%i` in the last `printf` as `avg` is a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

1) `avg = (float)total/50;` should be out of your `for` loop.

2) `total = total + num[i];` should be `total = total + value;`

3) Your `printf` statement should be:

```
printf("The average of all the numbers is %f \n", avg);
```

4) Also you are not using `num[]` array.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting 0 because you did not assign the `value` to your array element `num[i]`.
In you for loop, you should also do

```
num[i] = value;
total = total + num[i];
```

And you need to move the `avg` calculation out of the for loop.